# JavaFX - Databinding - Add an addition BooleanBinding

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, boolean-logic

Let's assume I have have a `visibleProperty()` of a Control, which is bound to a `BooleanProperty` somewhere in the application.

What i wanted to achieve is to add an additional binding in antoher piece of code to get sure that the visibility is e.g. always false, no matter of its existing or upcoming bindings. However it should never be possible to set the visiblity to true, if there is a binding which returns false. So I need to implement a kind of boolean logic.

The first attempt was to use OR/AND-concatinations.

```
tableColumn.visibleProperty().and(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> false));
```

But as you see in the following example, this can never work.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BooleanProperty a = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    BooleanProperty b = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);
    a.bind(b);
    System.out.println(a.get());
    a.and(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> false));
    System.out.println(a.getValue());    
}
```

Maybe someone of you has a more creative idea.

Thx, Marry

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense. `a.bind(b)` means that `a` will always have the same value as `b`. It sounds like you are trying to execute some code that changes what `bind` means: there's simply no way to do that. If you want the value of `a` to depend on some more complex expression, you would just bind to the more complex expression, e.g. `a.bind(b.and(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> false)));`

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can simply add an additinal binding to the `visibleProperty`.

**Example:**

The `visibleProperty` of the first `Button` is bound to the `selectedProperty` of the `ToggleButton`, therefore as you press the toggle, the button is visible or unvisible.

If the third button is pressed, a new binding is added to the `visibleProperty` of the first `Button` which always remains `false`. From this moment the `ToggleButton` has no effect.

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

Button b = new Button("Button");
ToggleButton tb = new ToggleButton("Make Button invisible");

b.visibleProperty().bind(tb.selectedProperty().not());

Button overrideBinding = new Button("Make Button invisible forever");
overrideBinding.setOnAction(e -> b.visibleProperty().bind(new SimpleBooleanProperty(false)));

root.setCenter(new VBox(b, tb, overrideBinding));
```

**Important note:** If you switch the order of the bindings (false at first then the binding with the `ToggleButton`) the result will be different. In this case the visibility will be changing based on the selected state of the toggle (you can think as the second one "overwrites" the first one).

**Note #2:** In your example when you are doing this:

```
a.and(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> false));
System.out.println(a.getValue());
```

on the first line you are creating a new `BooleanBinding` but you do not assign it to anywhere, therefore it has no effect on `a`.

You could update it to see the results as:

```
BooleanBinding andBinding = a.and(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> false));
System.out.println(andBinding.getValue());
```

**Note #3:** If you try to create a binding like in your example

```
a.bind(a.and(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> false)));
```

It will most probably result in a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Thank you. But this is not what I am looking for, because it is not assured, that there will be no other incoming bindings for this visibleProperty. So if there will be a forth toggle button, which sets the visiblity to true, the "Make invisible forever" -Button will have no effect anymore. Like I said I must concatinate the Binding to all existing AND incoming bindings

Comment: Quite strange usecase. What is the possible source of an additional binding? Normally the GUI controls are not exposed, so you are the only one who has direct control over them. So I do not really understand the fear behind. In any case: I doubt that it is possible without subclassing the exact `Node` or wrapping it to a class, that can handle a "binding-priority".

Comment: @MarryS A pretty strange idea but you could maybe add a changelistener that always sets the visibility to false and removes all other listeners but itself. Don't know if this will work but maybe it does the job

Comment: "Quite strange usecase" ... You are so right :/. It would take too much lines to explain it, but i can't do anything about it right now.

Comment: If a property is bound, you cannot set the value directly. It will result in a `RuntimeException`. In this listener you have to remove all of bindings at first with `unbind`. But e.g. if you have another listener on the property, that always sets the property to true, you are close to a `StackOverflowError` again^^. So: it's not so straightforward, that's the reason I mentioned the subclassing and the wrapping. Other thing: you can hide the Node from CSS also with a new pseudo-class (it can be also obviously overwritten) but, if you fear the mean external bindings, it can be a solution also.